# Behat - Check for broken image links

Tags: php, testing, behat

Is there a way to check with Behat, if on the page there is no images with broken / corrupted links ?

Answer (score 3):

I would propose to find all images on the page

```
$imageElements = $this->getSession()->getPage()->findAll('css','img');
foreach($imageElements as $image){
    $imgUrl = $image->getAttribute('src');
    $this->visit($imgUrl);
    //Here should be assertion of valid img,
    //F.e. if you are using goutte driver check that server response is not 500 or 404
    $this->assertResponseStatusIsNot(404);
}
```